# I want to retrieve auth code to take access_token using python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting error from server side. I need to take auth code to variable to get access to the access_token using python 3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: And what does this question have to do with the C programming language?

Comment: I don't have the access to tag the pyhton so I tagged the C

Comment: Maybe you didn't find the tag because it's spelled *python?* Anyway, even if you can't find the correct or otherwise suitable tag, don't add irrelevant tags. Tags are often used by readers to find relevant questions, and of course for searching.